syntax for batch handling of records
The following form
<%= form_with url: garment_measure_path(sequence: sequence), method: :patch do |form| %>
   <% garment_measures.each do |garment_measure| %>  
     <%= fields_for "garment_measure[]", garment_measure  do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :value_base, class: 'text-center', placeholder: garment_measure.value_base %> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

submits parameters to the controller with the goal of processing a batch of record updates simultaneously.
 Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"garment_measure"=>{"1"=>{"value_base"=>""}, 
"2"=>{"value_base"=>"4"}, 
"3"=>{"value_base"=>"44"}, 
"4"=>{"value_base"=>"3"}, 
"5"=>{"value_base"=>"36"}, 
"6"=>{"value_base"=>"32"}, 
"7"=>{"value_base"=>""}, 
"8"=>{"value_base"=>""}, 
"9"=>{"value_base"=>"XXS"}}, "commit"=>"submit", "sequence"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}

However the controller statement to group the records by id
grouped_garment_measures = params[:garment_measure].index_by{ |garment_measure| garment_measure[:id]}  
GarmentMeasure.update(grouped_garment_measures.keys, grouped_garment_measures.values)

leads to an error undefined methodindex_by' `  as the params are not an enumerable.  How should the param[:garment_measure] be transformed as an enumerable for proper handling ?

Your question is unclear. I understand that index_by is not available for ActionController::Parameters although you can easily convert those to a hash using the aptly named to_hash (or to_unsafe_hash). That being said the params are in the form of "2"=>{"value_base"=>"4"} so garment_measure[:id] will fail as garment_measure in this case would be ["2",{"value_base" => "4"}] resulting in no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)....

...If all you are trying to do is update based on the params then the index_by serves no purpose. Assuming the form of the Hash is {id => {attribute: value}} then all you need is GarmentMeasure.update(params[:garment_measure].keys,params[:garment_measure].values). See ActiveRecord::update

@engineersmnky Yes, this was the succinct line. I had that path by then went on a garden path having miscued on the strong params, hitting an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError  Resolution was to precede  line GarmentMeasure.update(params[:garment... with   params[:garment_measure].permit!
